# API File Download

Tags: bash, perl, shell, api

I have an API call that downloads a file to my computer. I'm trying to use the same API call to download using a script on Linux. I tried both of the below methods and they didn't work. However, when I paste the link on my browser, file starts to download after a second.

```
 curl -O --insecure https://(url) 

 wget https://(url)
```

I am also open to using PERL to do the same.

Comment: an the API call is ?! Use `wget` with `-d` to debug.

Comment: are you using self-signed ssl certificate?

Comment: Yes, but I am using --no-check-certificate

Comment: I was able to get it to work by writing a client in perl.

Comment: Perhaps there are some characters in your URL that had special meaning to your shell? You could try "echo <curl or wget command>" and compare the output to make sure it was not inadvertently modified by normal shell command-line processing.

Comment: Providing _actual_ URL may help to answer the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using the Perl CPAN module [REST::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client), I was able to send a request and then write the output to a file.